# How can I store this data for future use instead of JSON? (Powershell V2)

Tags: json, windows-7, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I work as an administrator in an enterprise environment, with the vast majority of systems running Windows 7 and to my chagrin... Powershell V2.

I've been developing a rather lengthy script on my workstation which is running Powershell V3, but have been verifying compatibility with a V2 environment, however I've run into a problem I can't seem to get around.

The script itself runs a handful of functions which all work fine, and stores their output in a series of variables, which I need to store in a data file for later use.  In a perfect world, I'd have everything upgraded to Powershell v3 and use JSON, as it fits the bill perfectly for what I'm trying to.

```
$table = [ordered]@{
Workstation = $global:MachineName
Date = $date = get-date -format MM-dd-yyyy
OSArchitecture = $global:OSArchitecture.OSArchitecture
HBSSAccess = $global:HBSS_Access
SCCMAccess = $global:SCCM_Access
WMIHealth = $global:WMI_Health
SCCMHealth = $global:SCCM_Health
WMIRepairAttempt = $global:WMI_Repair_Attempt
SCCMRepairAttempt = $global:SCCM_Repair_Attempt
WMIRepairResult = $global:WMI_Repair_Result
SCCMRepairResult = $global:SCCM_Repair_Result
}

[PSCustomObject]$table | ConvertTo-json | out-file -FilePath "C:\users\public\scriptdata\storage.json"
```

Now, that's how it runs in Powershell V3, and it does exactly what I'd like for it to, which is later catalogued by a server checking each PC for that data file and converts back into a usable object using the following:

```
$Data = Get-Content -Path "C:\users\public\scriptdata\storage.json" | out-string | ConvertFrom-Json
```

And that works great, again, on Powershell V3.  My understanding is that neither [Ordered] nor ConvertTo-JSON/ConvertFrom-JSON exist within Powershell V2.

What can I do to make this function in my environment?  Alternative data storage ideas would be acceptable as well.  I appreciate any help you guys can offer.

Thanks,
Tyler

Answer (score 0):

Hashtables are supported in PS2 so you could convert your data into CSV and sort on the fly. Remove [ordered] from your table definition

```
$table = @{
Workstation = $global:MachineName
Date = $date = get-date -format MM-dd-yyyy
OSArchitecture = $global:OSArchitecture.OSArchitecture
HBSSAccess = $global:HBSS_Access
SCCMAccess = $global:SCCM_Access
WMIHealth = $global:WMI_Health
SCCMHealth = $global:SCCM_Health
WMIRepairAttempt = $global:WMI_Repair_Attempt
SCCMRepairAttempt = $global:SCCM_Repair_Attempt
WMIRepairResult = $global:WMI_Repair_Result
SCCMRepairResult = $global:SCCM_Repair_Result
}
```

then you can export data

```
$table.getEnumerator() | sort key | select key,value| Export-Csv "C:\users\public\scriptdata\storage.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

and import it too and operate as you would on a csv

```
PS U:\Scripts> $Data = Import-Csv "C:\users\public\scriptdata\storage.csv"

PS U:\Scripts> $Data

Key                                                         Value
---                                                         -----
Date                                                        01-29-2014
HBSSAccess
OSArchitecture
SCCMAccess
SCCMHealth
SCCMRepairAttempt
SCCMRepairResult
WMIHealth
WMIRepairAttempt
WMIRepairResult
Workstation
```